# How to create external web form for case creation in salesforce, without using web to case functionality

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, integration, administration

I have a requirement to create a web form for external users (who are not using salesforce) to submit a case in salesforce. As for as I know Web-to-Case is not consistent in data transition so please help me in this scenario what is the best way to implement this functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "best way" to do this. Salesforce has many different options requiring various levels of complexity. For example, you can set up a Community, a Site, Email-to-Case, a SOAP- or REST-based API call, or even use a third-party AppExchange product. Each of these solutions will have tradeoffs in terms of performance, cost, implementation time, and other considerations. Note that web-to-case is perfectly fine if you just add some validation to the form input before allowing it to be sent to Salesforce. On the other hand, it also has daily limits, which is one of several considerations you should take into account.